# Picklist field not available for Record Types

Tags: picklist, record-type

In one of our Sandboxes we noticed one of the picklist fields(not the values, the field itself) is not under 'Picklist available for Editing' section while in other Sandbox it's still there.

But when we retrieve the object metadata file via Migration tool(from the same user account), the field is there for the record types. It's missing from the below Setup interface.

[image: Picklist missing from Record Type]
What else we need to check or any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Will you be able to provide some screenshot?

Comment: Added a screenshot to explain where I'm looking at

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the picklist field thats not available?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try out by creating another business process. Hope that will work for you. Once you have created this business process you will associated it to the record type upon creation or edit.